# How to represent sign function in range $[-1, 1]$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, notation

I have a function that is defined as follows:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $x \ge0$}, \\
-1 & \text{if $x<0$}.
\end{cases}$$
I would like to represent the above function by the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). Could you help me represent it
$$f(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)...???$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}\!\left(\mathrm{sgn}(x)+\frac12\right)
$$

Comment: Perfect. It is very simple and that is I need

Comment: And, as a byproduct, we have another way of writing $1_{\{0\}}$: As $\operatorname{sgn}(\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\frac12)-\operatorname{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: Reminds me of Stone's formula...

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)+g(x),
$$
where
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x=0$},\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Two common notations for such a $g$ are $\chi_{\{ 0 \}}$ or $1_{\{ 0 \}}$. The brackets, which might seem a bit superfluous, are there because the notation is read as "the indicator function of the set $\{ 0 \}$". (Sometimes we say "characteristic function" instead, though this term is taken by something else in certain other contexts.)

Comment: Can you represent it by only one equation. Is it possible

Comment: @user2938494 Writing it as one equation is just a problem of notation; I've written two common notations in the second sentence. But you could define your own notation for such a $g$ if you wanted.

Comment: $g(x)$ looks like the dirac function, Is it right?

Comment: @user2938494 : Not much, because $\delta(0) = \infty$

Comment: @user2938494 Not really; the Dirac delta is not a function, whereas this is actually a function. In particular, $g$ has integral zero while the Dirac delta has integral $1$.

Comment: Why don't you write directly $f(x)=sign(x)+\chi_{\{ 0 \}}(x)$? @Ian

Comment: @Fermat: it is more clear for new menber.

Comment: @Fermat I suppose I could have proceeded in the opposite order, writing $f(x)=\text{sign}(x) + \chi_{\{ 0 \}}(x)$ and then defined $\chi$. This seems like a matter of style, though.

Comment: Do you know any function in matlab to support represent f function. I can do sign function but I don't know second function

Comment: @user2938494 If v is a vector then v==0 is an array which is $1$ where v is 0 and 0 elsewhere. In general you should NOT use this, because in floating point arithmetic the problem of checking whether a number is zero is extremely unreliable.

Comment: @user2938494 : However, using Heaviside function you can say that $g(x) = (H(x) + H(-x)) - 1$ for example. Heaviside is in MATLAB (try `(heaviside(x) + heaviside(-x)) - 1`)

Comment: @servabat Interesting that MATLAB uses the convention heaviside(0)=1/2. It makes sense from e.g. the Fourier perspective but it is still interesting.

Comment: @servabat: it is always 0 in all case. Ivan: How to represent the g(x) function in matlab.Note that x can be a vector

Comment: @user2938494 : Indeed, because MATLAB uses the 1/2 convention... You can use `Pref::heavisideAtOrigin(1)` and then `(heaviside(x) + heaviside(-x)) - 1` should work

Comment: Could you represent your way by matlab function. I tried it but it is still 0

Comment: @servabat: Your function is only run in MUPAD "Use only in the MuPAD Notebook Interface."

Answer (score 1):

How about $$f(x) = \lim_{y \rightarrow x^+} \text{sign}(y)$$

Comment: lim is more complex. I just rewrite my function by sign. And implement it by matlab. Your function is so hard

Comment: It's pretty easy, and it's a single equation. When you say "I just rewrite the function by sign" it makes it sound like you've already succeeded in answering your question, so I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here. At any rate if you haven't finished implementing it, just look up how to do piece-wise functions in matlab. It would be a lot less effort than what you're doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

First note that there are several possible definitions of the sign function (and some of them accept $\text{sign}(0)=1$). Actually to be consistent, one can take the $\text{sign}$ function to be the [subgradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) of $x\mapsto |x|$ and so you have the choice to define $\text{sign}(0)=\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in [-1,1]$ (the subgradient of $|x|$ at $0$ is $[-1,1]$).

Anyway for a matlab use, you can set

> f = @(x) sign(x) + (x==0)

this matlab function satisfies your desired properties.